# PF1102T Clock Motor replacement

Tags: pool, timer

Can you buy just the clock motor instead of the whole PF1102MT mechanism?
I have this model (240v) on my pool that includes the freeze protection. The clock motor gear will not turn AND I do not know if the gear is even supposed to turn freely. It was working fine until the hard and long freeze here in Fort Worth. Lost power for a couple of days and things froze up. Had to replace some above ground plumbing. When we fired everything back up the clock wasn't working. I can still spin the timer with the on/off tabs and the manual knob all still work to turn the pump on. I see other clock motors that look very similar but do not have the same part number (WG1773 208/277v 60HZ). So my roughly $200 question is: can I buy just the clock motor by itself and save some $$$.
Can you buy just the clock motor instead of the whole PF1102MT mechanism?
Would appreciate any info on this.
Thanks

Comment: Looking similar is bad way of buying a replacement, for anything.  Need to match mounting, voltage and amps,and RPM, at bare minimum.  Make sure it is motor problem first, should usually spin freely if removed.  Try contacting company for parts or model numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can buy just the clock motor from Intermatic. Some good local hardware shops (typically those with heavy property management clientele) stock a variety of them. The number you posted (WG1773) is the clock-motor number you need.

And no, you typically would not be able to grab the toothed gear and turn it by hand...